# Error showing The emulator process for AVD was killed when booting the virtual device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I have created the sample android project "hello World" and created new Virtual Device from the AVD manager. later trying to run the app over AVD, was getting following error: "Error while waiting for device: The emulator process for AVD  was killed."

Android Studio: 2.0v
Project TargetVesrion: 23
AVD is Nexus5 with x86_64 CPU with API Level 23
[image]

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36841461/error-android-emulator-gets-killed