# ERROR Android emulator gets killed in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

After updating to Android Studio 2 when I try to run my application and choose an emulator, I wait for the emulator to start and it suddenly gets killed. I can see the emulator process for some minutes but never the GUI. In Android studio, I get the error

```
android studio Error while waiting for the device: The emulator process for AVD was killed
```

This happens even if I run the emulator outside Android Studio. I have tried both an Android 6 and an Android 4.4-based emulator.
Running on a Windows 7 x64 PC. Similar post to [another StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36526037/the-emulator-process-for-avd-was-killed-in-android-studio2) which was closed. I have tried various ram, VM heap, and resolution settings.

Comment: This happened mostly due to not enough space in c drive(min 4gb required),please clean c drive and check

Comment: this worked for me 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67288845/8899344

Comment: Well in my case i have 600gb free, and still getting this error

Answer (score 277):

I hit this issue trying to run Android API 30. In the end, I had to upgrade Android Emulator to `30.1.5` (it was `30.1.2` before this).

[image: Android SDK Tools settings]

Comment: I am on macbookpro running Catalina 10.15.5 and this worked. Thanks for the tip

Comment: Nothing was working so I took the brute force route and just went to `help -> Check for Updates...` and chose "Update All" to update everything in the list. Then restarted the IDE. I repeated this (restarting about 3X) until no more updates appeared. Then started the emulator via "cold boot now" in the dropdown arrow in AVD "actions" column. I'm on the canary version of "Artic Fox" and after all this, the emulator is finally working.

Comment: This solved problem on Windows also.
Had issue only when running API 30 (update emulator from 30.0.x to 30.3.5 fixed it)

Comment: Worked for Android S - API 31 - developer preview build

Comment: While i didnt have the same issue, this post is a good example of how if you update AVD< you have to check back in Android Studio that you have also dowloaded the matching SDK to make your app work with that new Emulator phone.

not super "intuitive" :) thanks for the picture @Soc

Comment: Worked for me as well on Mac Mojave.  VS for Mac was failing on updates so just used Android Studio to update via screenshot above and voila!  Awesome.

Comment: Upgrading to latest (32.1.13) didn't help :(

Answer (score 238):

I had the same issue, the problem was there is not enough space in my disk drive.. you can see details about your specific situation in layer 'Event Log' this layer regularly is at the bottom on Android studio, it was my output Log:

"02:45 PM   Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Not enough space to create userdata partition. Available: 3310.363281 MB at /home/user/.android/avd/my_Nexus_5X_API_27.avd, need 7372.800000 MB."

I had just 7 GB free, so just delete some GB's in my D.D. and it's working fine.

Comment: Clearing the disk worked for me. However, Event Log did not show any warning/error message of any kind that would indicate that disk space was the issue.

Comment: In AVD Manager, I edited the Virtual Device, clicked "Show Advanced Settings", and under "Memory and Storage", reduced the sizes of some of the storage options.  Then I was able to run the AVD.

Comment: @Sau001 It sounds strange that the Log does not show the error, however it is good that it has worked you

Comment: FYI, for me I think the disk filled when doing the initial install of the avd in question. The AVD screen thought it was ok, but it wasn't.  But removing ~/.android entirely and re-installing the images I wanted it started working.  (the logs may have shown something before I closed studio and restarted, but I didn't check them then)

Comment: I too needed to clear the disk, but didn't see any message indicating this could be my issue. This worries me. If anyone can contribute how to view the emulator's error logs I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: this did it for me

Comment: This one was my issue, thanks to bring this solution!

Comment: Worked for me thanks, the most endorsed solution might have been the best solution at the time, but this one is now more relevant.  For me I only had 200mb free, cleared space until I had 21GB free and it worked fine after that.

Comment: I have 274 GB available. I don't think that's the problem for me.

Comment: In my case, there was a file access error. AccessDeniedException

Answer (score 139):

For me it seems it was a problem that OpenGL didn't work on my machine.  I fixed it as follows:

1. Go to: Tools > Android > AVD Manager
2. Press the "edit" (pencil) icon next to your AVD
3. Change "Graphics" to "Software".

Comment: the "Graphics" options seems to only be available to devices without the Google Play Store enabled, as of Android Studio v3.5. Otherwise it stays set to "Automatic".

Comment: I couldn't change the settings because the field is muted to 'Automatic'. But I think the problem is potentially related to the graphic card, because after switching my gpu driver from X.Org X Server to Nvidia, the problem was resolved. I am using Ubuntu and always have graphics related issues.

Comment: Solved the problem but it is pretty slow in Software mode.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, after hours of searching and trying your answer solve the issue. Thanks

Comment: No Tools > Android menu for me.

Answer (score 72):

Check the **free space** of the emulator installation **drive** is more than 5 GB

Comment: In my case 5GB free space is not enough, after clean up to 20GB it works. Emulator nowadays might need more free space to run.

Comment: First in Emulator "wipe data" then start  Emulator

Comment: Note that the host drive may have to have MORE space then you set for device (e.g. I had 14GB free on my disk, 10GB was device, but it still wasn't enough, when I made 40GB free on disk, it started working)

Comment: C:\Users\username\.android\avd check there. If you dont use some avd, delete them

Comment: the fking wipe data worked for me

Answer (score 50):

Install the Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator worked for me.

[image]

Comment: i had to do this and i also had to update the Android Emulator package

Comment: For me it was already installed but i had to update it. Thanks.

Comment: Already latest version; still not working.

Answer (score 47):

This worked for me:

Tools -> SDK Manager -> SDK Tools (tab) -> Deselect 'Android Emulator' -> OK

Now, when you try to run your app, or launch device from AVD Manager, it will give the 'Install Emulator' error -> Click Ok.
This will automatically download the correct version.

Comment: and... increase ram memory. I changed from 1536 to 7536 MB RAM, and now it starts. Slowwwwly but it works for Android 11.0 x86 / API 30. Also the emulated performance graphics may fail when set to Hardware in some computers, so we can leave it as Software GLES 2.0

Comment: Not sure what helped - if freeing up space on the hosting disk (even there was enough space, I had to actually make much more) or this, but then it magically started working :)

Comment: Didn't help for me :(

Answer (score 36):

For Android Studio v4.1 and above:

Menu -> Android Studio -> Preferences -> Tools -> Emulator

Uncheck Launch in a tool window option.

[image]

Comment: For me I was able to re-enable this setting after the emulator launched once as a standalone process. I.e. uncheck -> run emulator -> check -> run emulator.

Comment: then, this feature is not stable?

Comment: @AnggaAryaS This feature is new, so there are probably many bugs to be fixed

Comment: You mean File > Settings menu?

Answer (score 27):

This issue happens when you have two Android SDK installations on your machine and the environment variable "ANDROID_HOME" points to the wrong location.

To fix it go to Android Studio settings, find the proper Android SDK location, update the environment variable and restart Android Studio / your PC.

[image]

Comment: the ANDROID_HOME changed after Installing Nativescript, and following your answer fixing the issue thanks

Comment: Had the same issue with nativescript. I have changed the path from c:\users\.... to C:\Android\android-sdk, then installed and upgraded emulators and everything started working.

Comment: This was it for me after trying 4 other solutions here :) Just a heads up, I needed to restart Android Studio for the new environment variable to take effect

Comment: I have no ANDROID_HOME env var.

Answer (score 27):

I resolved the same issue by updating the Android Emulator.

Steps:

```
1. In Android Studio Go to TOOLS
2. SDK Manager
3. Android SDK
4. SDK Tools
5. Update the Android Emulator.
```

Then it will Run.

Check this for reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/64384372/13952516

Answer (score 23):

Faced a similar issue, tried the above solutions as well and it didn't work.

Would like to suggest a simple solution which could help if the above suggestions didn't address the issue.

**Solution** -  Try cleaning up space in the system. My problem was I had only 1GB left while trying to launch the emulator after cleaning up space got 8GB and was able to launch the emulator.

Comment: Yeah, this solved my issue too. Obviously the simulated phone needs to use some Disk space for its memory and internal storage space.

Comment: I had the same problem. I did BIOS settings, virtualization, kvm, install different Android versions. All to realize, thanks to your comment, that I simply don't have enough space to launch it!

Answer (score 15):

In my case, after installing the  [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019 (both x86 and x64 version)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0), the issue is solved.

**But wait! Why did I know this? I will tell you my experience.**

When your program meets a bug, the first thing you need to do is finding the log to debug. But where is the log file that records all the events of the Android emulator? Click **Help→Show log in Explorer. And then a new window is oepned, where a file called idea.log is located, and that log file is what we are looking for.**

But this file may has recorded too much verbose info, so let's do following processes to get a more simple one:

·Exit Android Studio

·Delete the idea.log

·Open Android Studio

·Click Tools→ AVD Manerger

·Start one of emulators you have created, and needless to say, the error will occur again. But the idea.log will be created and the error is recorded into the log file now!

·Exit Android Studio.

·Open the idea.log and begin to analyze it.

·Search "emulator", and in my case there are 2 messages catching my eyes:

```
INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: E:\cache\SDK\emulator\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5_API_22 

INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)
```

Obviously, the "exit code 1073741515" is something important, and actually many people have asked what it means in StackOverFlow, but unfortunately, I can't find any useful info about it. So let's pass it and focus on the first message.

Open the command line (Press "Win"+"R" → Enter "CMD" → Click "OK"), copy the above message `E:\cache\SDK\emulator\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5_API_22`
and paste it to the command line. Press Enter.

**I totally didn't know what this command meaned, but it's reasonable to deduce that Android Studio ran this command and resulted in the error**, so I will try to reproduce the issue.

After that, an error window pop up, saying "**...VCRUNTIME140_1.dll is missing...**". I know I have been close to the answer. So I serch "VCRUNTIME140_1.dll Missing" on google, and people [said](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/vcruntime1401dll-missing-where-to-get/268964c7-6910-4cdd-9a96-b03f4c1f6954) that "**downloading and installing both the x86 and x64 versions of the Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 - 2019 Redistributable will resolve this problem**".

So I [download](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0) both the x86 and x64 version and install them. After doing this, I run the emulator again, and everything goes well.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, it helps me to solve the problem. And for others, if you have separate versions installed like VS 2015, the combined package will replace it, you don't need to uninstall the separate version.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining. You save my day.

Comment: Thanks! For me that was the key: "Click Help→Show log in Explorer. And then a new window is oepned, where a file called idea.log is located", a silly thing when you know it, essential when you don't!

Comment: info about the log is great. Sadly, I see nothing in the log other than happy-path stuff and then "VCPU shutdown request" :(

Answer (score 14):

In android studio version 4.0 (WINDOWS), I could find the solution by just checking android studio welcome screen and clicking on the "Events" dropdown **AFTER trying to launch the emulator** (hence after getting the error):
[image]

the events section clearly shows that ANDROID_SDK_ROOT was not set in my system.

In a nutshell, whenever you see such error when starting the emulator, just check the "events" section in the welcome to android studio screen to find the real problem.

Beware that if ANDROID_HOME is not set properly, it will still tell you that ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is broken.

Comment: In my case (AVD in Android Studio 4.1/MacOS Catalina) I had forced the ANDROID_HOME and ANDROID_SDK_ROOT in my ~/.zprofile. After commenting those lines and a reboot the AVD images started working fine:  
  
`#export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/share/android-sdk  
#export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/usr/local/share/android-sdk`  
  
I've also installed Intel x86 emulator as answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/52327730/1245926 by @simon-schnell

Comment: I don't see events button/menu in welcome screen (2022.2.1)

Answer (score 13):

You need to update the following tools.
[image]

Comment: In case already updated, just uninstall and reinstall `android emulator` from SDK Tools

Comment: nope. didn't help.

Answer (score 11):

If you're on the Apple Silicon (M1) chip, make sure you're using an ARM64-based emulator:

[image]

If you're not, create a new Virtual Device and use the `arm64-v8a` image from *Other images*.

Comment: It's strange that android studio doesn't recognize the architecture and not set it propertly. Worked!

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out... at least I can get something running in the emulator. Unfortunately, they don't have any images for the Android TV yet that seem to be working. Any idea how to run on Android TV? There are ARM images but none of them are ARM64

Comment: Doesn't fix it for me

Answer (score 10):

**Simple solution 2021**

1. Go to AVD Manager
   [image]
2. Find the emulator you are trying to use and then click on the down arrow[image]
3. Select the option Show on Disk
4. delete every file that ends with **.lock**[image]
5. Runs again the emulator and after this will initialize

Answer (score 9):

Please check your free space on your disk also. I had a same problem and finally I got I need to free up space to fix this.

Answer (score 8):

- Go to: Tools > Android > AVD Manager and Press the "edit" (pencil)
  icon next to your AVD , Change "Graphics" to "Software".
- work on my Windows 10 machine and ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I couldn't change the settings because the field is muted to 'Automatic'. But I think the problem is potentially related to the graphics, because after switching my gpu driver from X.Org  X Server to Nvidia, the problem was resolved. I am using Ubuntu and always have graphics related issues (having integrated nvidia doesn't help :(.

Comment: Confirmed works for me - Remember to pick a device that lets you change this setting. (One without Google Play Store icon next to it)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44328225/cant-change-emulated-performance-of-avd-in-android-studio

Comment: Sadly, didn't help.

Answer (score 8):

**If your username is not in ascii/ has spaces** then this may help, as I tried all of the solutions here and couldn't fix this problem:

Note: I found this solution on [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AOK9ZxiBOGg&lc=UgzpyHsqvCHYeJGbkJN4AaABAg.9G969oZIG9W9GIU4UvUclO) video, suggested by a user called "tatachka", this is her comment (she kindly let me share it here).

> For example, I had this path
> c:\Users\Таня.android\avd\Nexus_One_API_24.avd My name in Windows is
> Таня, written in Cyrillic in windows encoding (cp1251). I changed the
> path to e:\Distribu\AVD.android\avd\Nexus_One_API_24.avd I moved
> files from disk C there and edited Nexus_One_API_24.ini changing the
> path in it and everything worked.
>
> How to change the folder path: My computer -> properties -> advanced
> system parameters -> environment variables - > lower 'New...' button:
> variable name:   ANDROID_SDK_HOME variable value:   e:\Distribu\AVD
> (in my case)
>
> After the reboot, a new folder(.android) appears in the folder
> e:\Distribu\AVD  containing the 'avd' folder

EDIT: For clarification, the idea here is that you don't want the path to have non-ascii characters. I moved it to *C:\programs_that_cant_read_hebrew* (and preformed the other steps) and it worked just fine.

EDIT: changed "English" to "ascii/ spaces" after the comments

Comment: I just had exactly this. My surname has an Umlaut so the path to AVD included non-ascii chars. I got a warning that I should move the SDK because of this, but it doesn't warn about the AVD.

The SDK location can be changed in the Android Studio SDK Manager but I had to set the environment variable ANDROID_AVD_HOME to the new location of AVD

Comment: My user name has spaces, and resulted in the same issue. moved it out of my user name and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 8):

I get this same error if you upgrade the emulator to version 30+ and run mac < 10.15

You see the real error if you run it from commandline

> ~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator -avd `<name>`

```
emulator: Android emulator version 30.5.3.0 (build_id 7196367) (CL:N/A)
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/IOUSBHost.framework/Versions/A/IOUSBHost
```

You can fix this to upgrade to Big Sur or downgrade the emulator with these steps.

- wget https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-darwin-6885378.zip
- unzip emulator-darwin-5395263.zip
- mv ~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator ~/Library/Android/sdk/previous-emulator
- mv emulator ~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator
- cp ~/Library/Android/sdk/previous-emulator/package.xml ~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/package.xml

Check if it succeed:

- cd ~
- ~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator -version

> 28.0.25.0

- ~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator -list-avds

Source https://groups.google.com/g/flutter-dev/c/uEthfwjZBAQ/m/HSFqTgYsAgAJ

Edited April 8th 2021: I updated the emulator link to a newer version as mentioned in the comments

Comment: I downgraded the emulator with the version mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/64301909/340175 which is a slightly newer release of the emulator than the one you're using AFAIK. Here's the link to it https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-darwin-6885378.zip I've also raised an issue so Google are aware of the issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/183295965 you're welcome to 'star' the issue so they'll know how many people it's affecting.

Answer (score 7):

My case was: GOOGLE PLAY.

My virtual device was Pixel 4... 
As shown on pic, Pixel4 has Google Play support, so that it give this error: " The emulator process for AVD Pixel4 was killed."
It gives error on Android Studio 4.1.1.

So that, I created a new virtual device(Pixel 4XL) and selected "SOFTWARE" for emulated performance...

Because this device doesnt have Google Play support, it worked for me.

[image: GOOGLE PLAY SUPPORT]
[image: SOFTWARE MUST BE SELECTED]

Comment: My case was the Graphics, it only worked once I selected Software. I wonder if it's a conflict with my Nvidia card...

Answer (score 6):

goto tools>android>sdkmanager and update emulator and install related API level.It worked for me

Answer (score 6):

### To summarize the above:

1. Install and reinstall HAXM 7.5.6 (only available version) under 'Android SDK' settings. Try downloading it manually, even other versions (they don't work with Android SDK), installing it from the Android/Sdk folder, etc.  **sc query intelhaxm** in cmd should show if it is running correctly.
2. Virtualization is enabled in your BIOS and has been tested
3. Made sure the PATH variables are correct (ANDROID_HOME / ANDROID_SDK_ROOT) but NOT (ANDROID_SDK_HOME) to the folder in your settings per [Here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables). Otherwise, you will see EVENTS on the Android Studio splash screen.
4. Try unchecking / rechecking **Launch in a tool window** in Emulator settings (and even Enable Device Frame in AVD settings)
5. Try rebuilding in several different combinations of android, different phones, etc (but with same levels and packages ... 30 for example)
6. Try Rebooting in several different configurations
7. Make sure all SDK Tools are up-to-date, and even try a fresh install of Android Studio. However, tried removing all of them, and adding them back.
8. Check your space, try to have 25GB maybe or more free
9. Check for Virtual Box, Antivirus Software, etc.
10. Open Android Studio with Administrator privileges

**RUNNING ON DUAL MONITORS / DOCKING STATION** ?

A) Run the emulator with everything unplugged, then plug back in your monitor! (Odd I know)... OR Better yet...
B) Create a **New Hardware Profile**, which will enable you to change **Graphics: Automatic** to **Software**.

Comment: Rebooting works after making configurations.

Comment: For me the problem was launching the emulator while the external monitors were connected through a USB dock. If I unplug the dock, the emulator launches just fine and keeps running after plugging the dock back in.

Edit: Setting the laptop display as the primary monitor and launching the emulator, without unplugging the dock, also works.

Answer (score 6):

This was working for me. You must update to android studio to latest version and then follow step below to update sdk tool:

1. Tools -> SDK Managers
2. Select Android SDK
3. Tab on SDK Tools
4. Check to update options available.[image]
5. Press ok button
   After that this procedure will take you some minutes, after it completed, everything will works fine.

Answer (score 6):

Despite the question has been asked specifically for Windows, I will give my answer for **MacOS 11.4 Big Sur**, since this thread is the first hit on google when searching for this issue, and none of the answers already given solved the problem for me.

I found the solution to my problem [here](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-fix-android-studio-emulator-issue-the-emulator-process-for-avd-was-killed-db74cb02a359) - for retention reasons, i will repeat the detailed steps anyway:

1. open `Terminal` and go to the directory `/Users/<username>/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/`
2. create an xml file named `entitlements.xml` with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" 
     "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
     <plist version="1.0">
     <dict>
         <key>com.apple.security.hypervisor</key>
         <true/>
     </dict>
     </plist>
```

3. resign the emulator

`codesign -s - --entitlements entitlements.xml --force qemu-system-x86_64`

4. start the simulator

Comment: This fix worked great, I'm also on MacOS 11.4 Big Sur. The weird thing was that my Android emulator was working great before. Maybe I don't remember my MacOS updating ‍♂️

Answer (score 6):

I know so many people have given answers to this question many have valid points as well.
I have tried all the above possible ways, but it was not working, after reading logs from the android studio, I came to know it was a storage issue, for the emulator keep 11 GB space free and it will work.

Comment: Multiple posts earlier than yours mention disk space.

Answer (score 5):

For me it was a problem of available space left in my computer and deleting unnecessary files solved the problem. Causes are vary from situations and you should see event tab which detailed event log are showed.

Answer (score 5):

1. In Android Studio Go to Help -> Show logs in explorer
2. Try to run the Emulator again of the errors are as below :

handleCpuAcceleration: feature check for hvf
cannot add library vulkan-1.dll: failed
cannot add library vulkan-1.dll: failed

3. Then install Microsoft VS Code and go to below path

C:\Users<User>\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code

4. Copy the vulkan-1.dll and paste in  below path

C:\Users<User>\AppData\Local\Android\emulator\lib64

For me this solutions worked

Answer (score 4):

For me, just deleting ANDROID_SDK_HOME from the environment variable list solved the problem

Comment: Which environment variable list?

Comment: Whoa! This was the one that worked me: / Thank you very much hehe!

Answer (score 4):

I tried every single answer in here but none of them worked, but finally I got it working when I run it on an emulator device with Android API 28. I think the problem is the emulator device couldn't run Android API 30.

[image: Android API 28]

Answer (score 3):

I think this is problem of Android studio 2 Update or Problem to solve please Update also Android sdk version also then work properly.

Comment: I have updated the android studio and the related SDKs but still same issue. find the attached screenshot link (http://i.stack.imgur.com/rgfgx.png)

Answer (score 3):

Update your Android SDK via Android SDK Managager.
It will probably work fine!

Answer (score 3):

I also had problem like this.

fix:

- **1**. Choose one of the older version for Android VDM(System image) - first,I used a version 28(It was OREO in my case) after that I switched to older one , to 25(NOUGAT).
- **2**. Change "Graphics" to "Software".

Answer (score 3):

Hello Everyone in Android programming...
I have same issue **Android emulator gets killed** but get rid of this issue successfully and android emulator run properly by doing following things...

1. Firstly, I updated my SDKs from android studio SDK manager but issue does not resolved.
2. Secondly, I have faced problems regarding my **computer C Drive space where path of SDK folder is located. My C Drive space is running very low and does not allow me to update SDK from android studio showing me error and my Android emulator gets killed then I moved my SDK folder from C Drive to another drive D which have huge space available, then Changed my sdk folder path form android studio and restart it and matter resolved successfully.** Cheers...
   Best Regards

Answer (score 3):

**It's happened to me before. It should solved now by upgrading to Android Studio 4.1.1**

Please ensure you all these ticked on SDK tools

- Google Play Intel x86 Atom System Image
- Android Emulator
- Android SDK Platform-Tools & Build-Tools

Restart the Android Studio. it seems work

Comment: In fact, the problem is in 4.1.1 but not 4.1.

Answer (score 3):

This error is so generic that this symptom could be because of any one of a million completely different problems.
What you have to do is to find more info about what is happening, so you don't look like a blind chicken pecking at unappetizing rocks.
So lets us get the debugging steps:

- first thing is to find the logs of Android studio. In doubt, stackoverflow already has a section to help you [How to find the logs on android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19784877/how-to-find-the-logs-on-android-studio). The text file should be named: "idea.log". You can open it with notepad, but only open it after android studio is closed (in windows 10).
- There will be a lot of events inside. Search by "manager.EmulatorProcessHandler" and the last date that you had the error. A good trick to facilitate your life, after having found the log file, is to close Android studio: delete the log file; reopen android studio and retry to open the emulator. The log file will be recreated with a lot less history and so it will be so much easier to search.
- In my case, i found: `manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Another emulator instance is running. Please close it or run all emulators with -read-only flag.`. Given that, it is easy to solve. I just had to open a process manager and terminate the emu process that didn't correctly close for some unknown reason.
- Of course, in our case the log will be completely different. But now you have a clue of the hidden criminal.

Answer (score 3):

I tried all the answers above, and none of them work. I eventually fixed the issue by doing the following:

1. open SDK manager
2. under SDK platform, uncheck all checked package, hit ok
3. open AVD manager, click the download button next to your virtual device
4. launch the device, this should be able to fix the issue
5. reopen SDK manager and recheck your desire platform

that's all!! hope this helps you as well, cheers

Comment: I have no download button in Device Manger.

Answer (score 2):

Go to SDK Manager and see if there are any updates on the emulator & build tools that need to be updated.

Answer (score 2):

For me I was running Arm instead of x86. Solved by installing the correct Image (x86_64 for example).

Answer (score 2):

**I reinstalled the Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)**

Prior to that I tried many things, but only one worked:

Configure-> Settings -> Appearance & Behavior\System Settings\Android SDK -> SDK Tools (tab) -> Deselect 'Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)' -> OK

Now, when you try to run your app, or launch device from AVD Manager, it will give the 'Install Emulator' error -> Click Ok. This will automatically download new 'Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)' and I selected  512 RAM and it worked.

After that I did all these process again and selected 2 GB of RAM and it still worked.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem. Tried different solutions as mentioned like

- Changing "Graphics" to "Software"
- Updating android studio sdk to latest release
- Invalidate cache/restart android studio

But the issue was my disk was full which and the emulator couldn't save the necessary files. So if anyone faces this issue, please make sure you have at least 10GB free space (as for android 11 installation in pixel 4 2021)

Comment: Thanks, my problem was the free space of the hard disk.

Comment: Thanks, my issue was using hardware for graphics. Guess having 3 monitors was the issue. Switching it to software works for me

Answer (score 2):

If you added these into **~/.zshrc** (or **~/.zprofile**, ...) in MacOS:

```
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=...
export ANDROID_SDK_HOME=...
```

it can cause this error.

**Remove or comment these lines then restart Android Studio** and it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

If your HAMX is installed and turning to Software didn't help try to check if virtualization is enabled in BIOS. You need to go to BIOS and enable it

Answer (score 1):

I tried to edit AVD with a new System image and voila! it worked!
I had Nexus 5X API 24

Answer (score 1):

this issue can also happen when `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` environment variable is pointing to wrong location

Say path to `.android` folder is `E:\Android\.android`

Then `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` environment variable value should be `E:\Android`

Answer (score 1):

Best 5 options to resolve this Error the emulator process for avd was killed

```
given option are checkpoints, check it out one by one.
Error Solution Option 1
Possiblity:
HAXM may not installed in System
HAXM - Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager
Solution:
SDK Manager > Check for HAXM installer
install it, if HAXM not installed
=======================================

Error Solution Option 2
Possiblity : 
Low disk size to load Emulator
Latest AVD with API level 30+ required approx 7 GB disk space
Solution:
Free space from disk where AVD is located

=======================================
Error Solution Option 3
Possiblity :
Configured AVD API may not available in SDK Manager
As an Example:
if Emulator with API level 30, same package of API 30 should be installed in SDK

Solution:
Install same version of SDK Platfrom from SDK manager,
as same as Emulator – AVD API

=======================================
Error Solution Option 4
Possiblity :
Configuration error in Old AVD 

Solution:
Recreate AVD with latest available update
Help > check for update, if component Android Emulator Update is available, install it
delete older AVD and create Fresh AVD

=======================================
Error Solution Option 5
Possiblity :
Embedded AVD not properly load with available image

Solution:
Launch AVD as independent component,
After success close it and lauch within Android Studio
Emulator inside Android Studio
=======================================

before apply all of above once restart you System, try it.
```

for more help with video support, watch [How to fix AVD was killed](https://youtu.be/AOK9ZxiBOGg)
i think it may help you.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was resolved after I tried a lower version of Pixel and Android.

Comment: Same; I'm seeing an issue on Android 11 (API 30) on Pixel 4 emulated devices, but Android 10 (API 29) works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue.
I changed ANDROID_HOME path on environment variables.
And then I copied 'avd' folder, which emulator installed in into 'sdk' folder(ANDROID_HOME path).
*** You can find 'avd' folder by clicking 'Show on Disk' in AVD manger.
I restarted the emulator and then it is running well now.

Answer (score 1):

**If you use McAfee Antivirus and Windows 10 this might help you:**

Uninstalling and reinstalling Android Emulator as snehatilak suggested initially helped in my case, though the next day the emulator was dead yet again.

I found that McAfee antivirus had quarantined the file AVD.conf that had been in C:\Users[username].android\avd[avdImage]\

After restoring AVD.conf and excluding it from scans it seems to be ok again.

This all started 02.02.2021 after what I guess was an McAfee update.

**Here are the steps:**

First go to 'Quarantined items' under Settings and restore the AVD.conf file
[image]

Then go to 'Real-Time Scanning' under Settings and exclude AVD.conf in each emulator you have created. (Located under C:\Users[username].android\avd[avdImage])

[image]

Answer (score 1):

None of these answers worked for me. I just created a new Virtual Device with the same exact settings and deleted the old one. New one worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I tried everything posted here but nothing worked. I solved this problem by updating my MacOS.

I was using **10.14 Mojace** and I updated it to the latest version, **11.2.1 Big Sur**.

When I tried to start the emulator from the command line, I received the error below. After some research, I discovered that Apple changed the locations of some system libraries after Catalina. I wasn't sure this was caused by it, but upgrading MacOS fixed it for me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have recently experienced this issue on my Mac 10.14.6 Mojave and the error is exactly same with the error in one of the answer from  gokhan-arik https://stackoverflow.com/a/66422209/15311922.

In his case, he solved it by updating to 11.2.1 Big Sur.
My solution is different.

Run from terminal:
`/Users/<username>/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator emulator -avd <Pixel_4_API_29>`

My error message:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/IOUSBHost.framework/Versions/A/IOUSBHost

  Referenced from: /Users/<username>/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64

  Reason: image not found

Abort trap: 6
```

I managed to get the IOUSBHost.framework from my friend's laptop and then upload it to google drive (in zip format), then do below steps:

- Restart mac and command+R to show recovery option, choose Safari icon to launch safari in recovery mode
- In safari, open the google drive link I have uploaded earlier, then download the zip file directly into /System/Library/Frameworks/ (it will automatically unzip)
- Restart the laptop.

Now, you can use emulator without updating to Big Sur.

And, here is the `IOUSBHost.framework.zip`. Use it on your own risk. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZP6rfMf-iW3j8iOGQC52zIHZcs4Haid1/view?usp=sharing

Comment: See alternative answer related to a bug introduced in emulator for macOS Mojave 10.14.6 (and likely other versions) - https://stackoverflow.com/a/66747909/132121

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you have enough space in c: drive - **Minimum should have 20GB free space**
2. If you have already created AVD then go to following location in your windows machine, from command line enter "`emulator -list-avds`".

   C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator>emulator -list-avds
   Pixel_2_API_29
3. Enter `emulator @Pixel_2_API_29`

   C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator @Pixel_2_API_29
4. You can see emulator launching.

**It worked for me** - other result found in internet didn't worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If from above no solution worked. Then download
both the x86 and x64 version and install them. After doing this, run the emulator again, and everything goes well.

Download link is : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0

Comment: Yes,it was just an update problem. Moreover not only images but within platforms and tools. Doesnt matter, I installed only 86x kind and it s ok

Answer (score 1):

On my Pop OS 20.04 LTS I got this when graphics drivers were updated but a system restart is pending. Upon a full system restart emulator images were working fine.

PS. On my machine whenever graphics drivers are updated system needs to be restarted otherwise some applications like Zoom and in this case Android emulators start crashing unexpectedly.

Answer (score 1):

Go to setting avd, change "Graphics" from "Quick boot" to "Cold boot".
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can get the error message details by running emulator from command line, e.g.:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>C:\Users\foo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -writable-system -avd emulator_foo
emulator: Android emulator version 30.6.5.0 (build_id 7324830) (CL:N/A)
emulator: ERROR: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file! Please ensure the file "kernel-ranchu" is in the same location as your system image.
emulator: ERROR: ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is undefined
```

Or alternatively via Android Studio IDE menu `Help` -> `Show Log in Explorer` -> open `idea.log` file -> run avd emulator again to see the error log updated in last few lines.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by killing the emulator `qemu-system-x86_64` in Windows Task Manager. Even though the emulator may not be open but it was still running in Task Manager. Killing the emulator and then running a cold boot from the AVD manager worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

`qemu-system-x86_64` kill this process on windows task manager it stay running even close the emulator. this process cause terminate the new process on start. The process name maybe different depend upon which System image you are using
following possible process name

```
 - qemu-system-i386.exe
 - qemu-system-aarch64
 - qemu-system-armel
 - qemu-system-x86_64
```

**kill one of them or all of them fix the issue**

Answer (score 1):

I also get this issue.
Working solution is.
Android Studio File-->Settings--> search for Emulator.
uncheck "Launch in tool window" option.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please check your .zshrc file in Mac (edit it by usign `vim ~/.zshrc` command) and remove any manually added path to ANDROID_HOME.

If you are not using .zshrc file then it may be .bashrc file.

Once removed restart your Android Studio and avd. This worked like a magic!!

Answer (score 1):

Go to `C:\Users\{{USERNAME}}\.android\avd` and remove the folder of avd target device and create a new virtual device in AVD manager. Now you click the run button. That's it

Answer (score 1):

If using a Mac Intel Core i7, choose "x86" as the ABI.  On the Virtual Device Configuration screen, there are three tabs:

1. Recommended
2. x86 Images
3. Other Images

Tabs 1 and 2 will most likely have the appropriate ABI for your computer.  But I once mistakenly went to Other Images and choose an ABI of arm64-v8a.

This answer is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/66059850/2848676 except it's for a Mac running Intel instead of Apple Silicon (M1) chip.

The generalization of both answers is to make sure the ABI you choose is compatible with your computer.  For example, on my "Other Images" tab it explicitly warned me "Consider using an x86 system image on an x86 host for better emulation performance" but unfortunately I didn't see this warning until later when I was trying to fix my problem.

Answer (score 1):

After 2 days of trying all the suggested solutions and other sources. None worked for me. It turned out I needed to enable virtualization support for windows using the add feature tool on windows os. Just got to your control panel and search for "Add feature" See attached image. All the best[image: Select Virtual Machine Platform as well as Windows Hypervisor Platform]

Answer (score 1):

I faced the similar problem. After searching for actual problem I found that my OS drive space (for Windows : C drive) where I installed Android Studio and SDK is running very low. At that time my C drive had only 1GB left. As per I know, android emulator won't run if the drive has less than 5GB of free storage, So I cleared my C drive by deleting unnecessary data and freed 25GB of space. Now I am able to run virtual emulators without facing any problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I'd to free some space in my hard drive (5 GB).

Answer (score 0):

Tried all solutions didnt help. My solution just create new device and it will work

Answer (score 0):

I changed Graphics to Software, Intel x86 Emulator was already installed and also restarted the PC. Nothing worked. It was the Hyper-V issue. I had turned it off for VMWare. I turned it on and restarted the PC and emulator worked. So please try Hyper-V.

Answer (score 0):

For my case i need to close Virtualbox

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with the **The emulator process for AVD Pixel_2_API_30 was killed** for a while now. I was trying to launch a Pixel 2 API 30 running android 11.0, I tried all the possible solutions but nothing seemed to work. I decided t use a different setup e.g. Pixel 2 API 28 running android 9.0, and it worked perfectly. I am not sure what causes the bug in the higher-level API or android version though... So my suggestion is to change the API and android version **IF** all of the other solutions didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that fixed it for me was to set the SDK_ANDROID_AVD variable (emulators data will be stored there).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is you have installed Android Studio in a non default directory(example c:\your_pesonal_directory), and maybe you have your user in ascii character(like papà) for this, android can't have acces to ascii directory

For resolve this on Win10:

1. Go in C:\users\your user name\
2. Move the directory .android to another directory example
   C:\AndroidSDK\ .android
3. Create ambient variable(go in settings and in a search toolbar write ambient variable)
   and name it: ANDROID_SDK_HOME
4. Select the new path for ANDROID_SDK_HOME: C:\AndroidSDK\ .android
5. Restart Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

My tricky solution is to try to start another emulator, then start this broken emulator.

In my case(`A Main 256 Heap` is broken), I will start `A Main 512 Heap`, then start `A Main 256 Heap`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me (and I saw online a few others ran into this), it was because I had [Riot's Vanguard](https://support-valorant.riotgames.com/hc/en-us/articles/360046160933-What-is-Vanguard-) software running in the background. It wasn't enough to kill the process in the tray (I'm on Windows), I had to set it to not run on startup and then restart my computer. After that, I was able to launch my virtual device just fine.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has occurred to me when I changed my SDK location from a disk to another disk, due to limited disk space problem, while doing this some files may got corrupted or lost, after a bit of digging I found out that my SDK was partially installed(according to the SDK manager).
All I have to do to solve this problem was to redownload the rest of the files from the SDK manager.

Answer (score 0):

The best to discover the issue is looking the log

```
cd /Library/Android/sdk/emulator/
./emulator  -list-avds
./emulator @name-emulator
```

https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/how-to-downgrade-android-emulator-on-macos-6e611d2d2bcb

Answer (score -1):

May be installation issue or some package/plugin not installed properly.
So reinstalling android studio. It's worked for me.