# Emulator can't find 'Linux version ' string in kernel image file

Tags: linux, android-emulator, ubuntu-14.04, android-source

I was building AOSP for the Nexus Player and after successful compilation I tried to run the emulator and the message I received is:

> emulator: ERROR: Can't find 'Linux version ' string in kernel image
>   file: /home/mita/Work/Nexus/out/target/product/fugu/kernel

I can't find anything about this, somebody please help.

The full output is:

> emulator:Found ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT: /home/mita/Work/Nexus/out/target/product/fugu emulator:Found build
>   target architecture: x86 emulator:Looking for emulator-x86 to emulate
>   'x86' CPU emulator:Probing program: ./emulator64-x86 emulator:Probing
>   program: ./emulator-x86 emulator:Probing path for: emulator64-x86
>   emulator:return result:
>   /home/mita/Work/Nexus/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/emulator64-x86
>   emulator:Found target-specific emulator binary:
>   /home/mita/Work/Nexus/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/emulator64-x86
>   emulator:GPU emulation is disabled emulator: Running
>   :/home/mita/Work/Nexus/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/emulator64-x86
>   emulator: qemu backend: argv[00] =
>   "/home/mita/Work/Nexus/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/emulator64-x86"
>   emulator: qemu backend: argv[01] = "-verbose" emulator: Concatenated
>   backend parameters: 
>   /home/mita/Work/Nexus/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/emulator64-x86
>   -verbose emulator: found Android build root: /home/mita/Work/Nexus emulator: found Android build out: 
>   /home/mita/Work/Nexus/out/target/product/fugu emulator: Read property
>   file at
>   /home/mita/Work/Nexus/out/target/product/fugu/system/build.prop
>   emulator: Cannot find boot properties file:
>   /home/mita/Work/Nexus/out/target/product/fugu/boot.prop
>
> emulator: Found target API sdkVersion: 25
>
> emulator: virtual device has no config file - no problem emulator:
>   using core hw config path:
>   /home/mita/Work/Nexus/out/target/product/fugu/hardware-qemu.ini
>   emulator: found skin-specific hardware.ini:
>   /home/mita/Work/Nexus/development/tools/emulator/skins/HVGA/hardware.ini
>   emulator: autoconfig: -skin HVGA emulator: autoconfig: -skindir
>   /home/mita/Work/Nexus/development/tools/emulator/skins emulator: found
>   skin-specific hardware.ini:
>   /home/mita/Work/Nexus/development/tools/emulator/skins/HVGA/hardware.ini
>   emulator: keyset loaded from: /home/mita/.android/default.keyset
>   emulator: trying to load skin file
>   '/home/mita/Work/Nexus/development/tools/emulator/skins/HVGA/layout'
>   emulator: skin network speed: 'full' emulator: skin network delay:
>   'none' emulator: autoconfig: -kernel
>   /home/mita/Work/Nexus/out/target/product/fugu/kernel emulator: Target
>   arch = 'x86' emulator: Auto-config: -qemu -cpu qemu32 emulator: ERROR:
>   Can't find 'Linux version ' string in kernel image file:
>   /home/mita/Work/Nexus/out/target/product/fugu/kernel

Comment: Which command did you use for compiling? Also can you post the list of files available in /home/mita/Work/Nexus/out/target/product/fugu/ ?

Comment: Sorry for not answering. I just posted the solution to the problem, but here are the files if you need them:
2ndbootloader          installed-files.txt       recovery.id
android-info.txt       kernel                    recovery.img
boot.img               module-info.json          root
build_fingerprint.txt  obj                       symbols
clean_steps.mk         previous_build_config.mk  system
data                   ramdisk.img               system.img
dex_bootjars           ramdisk-recovery.img
gen                    recovery

Answer (score -5, accepted):

To answer my own question:

You cannot run the build on the emulator if you compile for fugu - Nexus Player build.

Answer (score 146):

I was having this error and the cause was my Emulator running an old version. I went to SDK Manager and updated the Android Emulator

`Tools > SDK Manager > SDK Tools > Android Emulator > Mark it checked to force update > Accept`

After this, the emulator ran correctly

Comment: For updating from the command line, go to `< Android Sdk dir >/cmdline-tools/latest/bin` and run `./sdkmanager --update`. This will update all packages to the lateset version. Note: `< Android Sdk dir >` is usually `~/Android/Sdk`

Answer (score 13):

See @voghDev answer above,

> Tools > SDK Manager > SDK Tools > Android Emulator > Mark it checked
> to force update > Accept

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I was also having this error and the cause was my Emulator running an old version. I went to SDK Manager and updated the Android Emulator

I followed the steps of @voghdev

`Tools > SDK Manager > SDK Tools > Android Emulator > Mark it checked to force update > Accept`

And also make sure enough space is available for the emulator to run.

it requires around 8gb of disk space.

After this, the emulator ran correctly

Answer (score 2):

[image]Tools
SDK Manger
SDK Tools..

Here follow one simple Trick.

1. If the (Android Emulator)CheckBox is already checked.
2. **Uncheck the checkbox.**
3. Apply
4. Ok
5. Again Open the TOOLS-->SDK MANAGER-->SDK TOOLS
6. **Check the Android Emulator CheckBox**

By doing this old setting will be by default erased.
New Setting of the emulator will available.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zk08n.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check your Android SDK settings -> SDK Tools
enable HAXM installer (if you have Intel)
[like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLEc0.png)

it helped me, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Simply just go to Tools > SDK Manager > SDK Tools
and update what might be available under your selected choices.

It could many things:

- Android SDK Build-Toolsxxx
- Android Emulator
- Intel x86 Emulator Accelator (HAXM installer)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when building AOSP then launching the emulator **from the same terminal**

Late post for OP, but I hope this helps others building for earlier versions of AOSP (OP posted build for API 25).

**Problem:**

As I'm sure you're aware, to configure an AOSP build, you run:

1. `$ . build/envsetup.sh`
2. `$ lunch` (and then select your build target)

In `envsetup.sh`, if you look near the bottom of the `function lunch()`, there is a call to `set_stuff_for_environment`. Within `function set_stuff_for_environment()`, there is a call to `setpaths`.

`function setpaths()`, as the name suggests, adds some paths to the `$PATH` variable for your AOSP build to run correctly. One of the paths added to `$PATH`, is a version of the `emulator` command that is packaged with AOSP.

Since the path to the AOSP emulator will be found first in your `$PATH`, when running `$ emulator`, the system will use the AOSP version of `emulator` rather than your Android Sdk version of `emulator`.

In short, when you run `$ emulator` from the command line **after** running `$ lunch`, you'll be running the AOSP version of the `emulator` which is associated with what ever version of AOSP you're building for. (In my case it was an older version of AOSP)

**Solution:**

In addition to the other answers, which correctly point out you need to update the emulator version in your Android Sdk, you need to make sure that you are running the `emulator` command from the Android Sdk path and not from the AOSP emulator path.

To quickly check this you can use `$ which emulator`. This will show you the full path to the command that will be run when running `$ emulator`

The "correct" path should read something like:

- `/home/user-name/Android/Sdk/emulator/emulator`.

After running `$ lunch`, the path will read something like:

- `/home/user-name/aosp-home-dir/prebuilts/android-emulator/<target>/emulator`

**TL;DR**

If you are running `$ emulator` from the same terminal that you built AOSP with, try running `$ emulator` from a new terminal. In addition, you should confirm the path of the `emulator` command by using `$ which emulator`.

`$ which emulator` should be pointing to the emulator location of `< Android Sdk dir >/emulator/emulator`, **NOT** the AOSP version of the emulator.

NOTE: `< Android Sdk dir >` is typically installed to `~/Android/Sdk`

Comment: on Ubuntu don't `sudo apt install google-android-emulator-installer` but create alias for emulator pointing the program in the Android SDK dir. for me `alias emulator="/home/sagar/Android/Sdk/emulator/emulator"`
Thanks Yirmi!