# Android Emulator API 24 can't start due to kernel image file (kernel-ranchu)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Ok, so at some point while writing my app i started the emulator and got the error, that a kernel image file is missing.

> "Emulator error: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file"

So i recreated another device on the same API Level (24) and i got following error:

> Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Can't find 'Linux version ' string in kernel image file: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-24\google_apis_playstore\x86\kernel-ranchu

What i did so far:

- Created devices below and above API Level 24 -> Result is, that they work. Only API 24 seems to have this problem
- I  deinstalled and reinstalled Android Nougat (The android version with api 24) -> Result is, nothing changed still the same problem [Android version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDAGk.png)
- I deinstalled and reinstalled the Android Nougat SDK Plattform -> Result: Still get the error
- I deinstalled and reinstalled the SDK Tools and checked, that it's on the newest version -> Result: still get the error
- Moving a kernel-ranchu file from another system image (ex. API 25) doesn't help
- I completely deinstalled and reinstalled android studio as well as deleting all associated files and temporary files ->

> This is where it's interesting. When i now create a device on the newly installed, "clean" Android studio it starts. It still gives me this error "Emulator: emulator: WARNING: EmulatorService.cpp:448: Cannot find certfile: C:\Users\USER.android\emulator-grpc.cer security will be disabled." but the emulator starts and runs the app. However closing and attempting to start again will result in the error mentioned above to appear again and the emulator crashing.
> The mentioned file (kernel-ranchu) also changes from file type "file" to "system-file" and is being hidden. This does not happen with any other system image.

This is the only question i found on stack overflow with my error, however it didn't fix my problem: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43089302/emulator-cant-find-linux-version-string-in-kernel-image-file)

Any other link either refers to questions about this error

> emulator: ERROR: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file!!
> emulator: ERROR: ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is undefined

(Which i also had at some point) or to some japanese or chinese sites which i sadly can't read.

I have to use Android Nougat API 24, so i can't just skip to another version.

I'm quite at a loss at what to do, so any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm getting this on macos, with an api level 30 emulator (x86)

Comment: @Carmen I fixed it by going to Tools>SDK Manager. Under SDK Platforms, I selected Android 10.0 (Q). Then under SDK Tools, I selected Android SDK Build-Tools, Android Emulator and Android SDK Platform-Tools. Make sure a tick is selected instead of a dash. Select Apply to update.

Comment: Thanks for the update!  In my case, I managed to solve it by updating some tools in the sdk manager (in particular the emulator tool, but there may have been other updates too)