# emulator: WARNING: Crash service did not start emulator: ERROR: Can't find 'Linux version ' string in kernel image file:

Tags: android, flutter

I was setting up flutter project for the first time, i did all the necessary steps to get on board. When i run flutter doctor, no issues are found with it. Then when when i wanted to run the emulator in VSCode it kept on failing to run the emulator after 60 seconds. I tried to run the same using an android studio there was this error "emulator: WARNING: Crash service did not start emulator: ERROR: Can't find 'Linux version ' string in kernel image file:".

I tried to check if android emulator was up to date in sdk manager and yes it is updated. am using
android studio version 4.1.0
android sdk manager 30.0.3

any help on how i can mitigate this, i would really appreciate.

Comment: Can you [check this please](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64008135/13558035)