# Cannot run AVDs with API 33 or higher from command prompt, showing this error: emulator: ERROR: Can't find 'Linux version ' string in kernel image

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, emulation, android-virtual-device

Executing the following command:

`emulator -avd Pixel_6_API_34`

shows the following error:

> emulator: ERROR: Can't find 'Linux version ' string in kernel image /home/*username*/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-34/google_apis/x86_64//kernel-ranchu

**However:**

- This virtual device can be opened using Android Studio's "Launch" button.
- I can also start other emulator devices with API 23 from the command line.

##### Error message from trying to run emulator from ubuntu 22.04 terminal

[image]

**I tried the following that didn't help:**

- Updating Android Emulator which [seemed to be helpful for some users.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43089302/emulator-cant-find-linux-version-string-in-kernel-image-file).
- Restarting