# emulator: ERROR: Can't find 'Linux version in Ubuntu 22.04.3

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu, android-emulator

My use case is to install Android Studio and make it able to launch the A13 android emulator via command. I was able to launch the emulator via device manager, but I was not able to launch the emulator via command.

This is the command that I used to launch the emulator via command

> emulator -avd AVD_NAME -writable-system (p.s. In Linux android terminal)

This is the output when I tried to launch emulator via command

> emulator: ERROR: Can't find 'Linux version ' string in kernel image file: /home/l0-teststation3/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-33/google_apis/x86_64//kernel-ranchu

This is my workstation spec:

- Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
- Kernel version 6.1.0-1026-oem (Not sure why it is not generic)
- Intel® Xeon® W5-2445
- Discrete NVIDIA RTX™️ A2000
- 64GB RAM
- VM acceleration enabled (With KVM installed and verified)
- Using Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 2
- Latest Emulator version 32.1.15

I have tried various methods and it's still not working:

1. [First method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43089302/emulator-cant-find-linux-version-string-in-kernel-image-file/64008135#64008135) - Not working
2. [Second method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49120854/how-to-downgrade-android-emulator) - Not working
3. Third method (Add {ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}/emulator in .bashrc - Not working
4. Fourth method (Uninstall and delete system image A13 Intel, then reinstall back) - Not working
5. Fifth method (Uninstall the whole Android Studio along with cache in .android, etc.)
6. Sixth method (Use another system image (i.e. system image without Google API, AOSP) - Not working
7. Seventh method (Tally with the version of android SDK, etc. with the working station (i.e. this is the second workstation that I setting up)) - Not working
8. Eighth method (Use all latest Android SDK, NDK, etc. and also using slightly old version) - Not working

Comment: The only thing you didn't mention is the command you are using to start the emulator

Comment: Thank you for your input @DiegoTorresMilano, I already put the command that I used to launch the emulator into my question

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but in my case (Ubuntu 22.04.4), I had an old emulator package installed.

```
$ dpkg -l | grep android
ii  google-android-emulator-installer 30.0.12+1  amd64 download and install Google's Android emulator binary
```

One I uninstalled the package, and reinstalled SDK from Android Studio/SDK manager (the first mentioned method), it started working.

```
$ sudo apt-get remove google-android-emulator-installer
```