# Trouble/ERROR running the emulator on android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator

[image: I got this message after trying many solutions and running the emulator a lot, Maybe this can help..]I am running Android studio 4 on Windows7
When I run my emulator, I get a Message saying **"The emulator process for AVD was killed"**, showing the below error in the event log,

***'Emulator: Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We will address this in a future release.
Emulator: deleteSnapshot: for default_boot
Emulator: Process finished with exit code 0'***

Can someone please help,
I have Haxim installed, I have installed the latest platform-tools

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR Android emulator gets killed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36841461/error-android-emulator-gets-killed)

Comment: can you show the configuration in android?

Comment: If you don't have to use Android Studio Emulator, Use Genymotion.

Comment: @AlejandroGonzalez ,I'm sorry I don't understand, can you clarify your question please,

Comment: @WowoOt I installed genymotion and downloaded a device, but there is an error- when I start the device I get a window telling "starting virtual device" and then it crashes saying 'player.exe has stopped'. (i have installed Virtualbox which is compatible with genymotion)

Comment: I installed the version with vbox included, and make sure you virtualization or VT-x is enabled from BIOS.

Comment: @WowoOt I tried all of these nothing worked, here is the lik to my SO question regarding this,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62570234/genymotion-emulator-error-starting-virtual-device-player-exe-has-stopped

Comment: I am having same issue, did you ever resolve this?  Android 8 works, but not Android 10+.

Comment: @MikeFlynn I think we will need a pc with high specs for that,(16gb ram min). I'm now testing my apps on my android device via usb debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Go to AVD manager > Create new AVD > select Nexus S API 30 > set ram and storage to minimal and you should be good to go.

Comment: This method didn't help me out, but maybe useful for others who may view this.