# Genymotion emulator Error starting virtual device, "player.exe" has stopped

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, emulation, genymotion, android-emulator-plugin

I have installed **Genymotion 3.1.0** with **VirtualBox 6.0** (updated versions are not compatible with gm as said on their website) on **Windows 7 64bit**. I have enabled vt-x and am running the **latest version of my graphics driver.**

I get the error ***"player.exe has stopped"*** error when I start the device I have downloaded. (I have also tried starting the device with Virtualbox open)

Can someone please help??
I have tried the solutions posted on similar outdated questions on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Genymotion 3.1.0 no longer supports Windows 7 officially, so it may not work correctly with your Windows in the future.
That being said, you can either try to purge Genymotion and re-install it (see https://support.genymotion.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002815177-How-to-uninstall-Genymotion-Desktop-completely-purge-) or try out Genymotion 3.1.1 beta at https://www.genymotion.com/download-beta/

The beta version is compatible with VirtualBox 6.1.X.