# Android Studio emulator being killed

Tags: android, android-studio

For some reason ever since I updated Android Studio to version 4.1, whenever I try to run the emulator I get this error:

```
Error while waiting for device: The emulator process for AVD Pixel_2_API_29 was killed.
```

I have tried reinstalling android studio, cold booting the device and literally everything I could think of.

Comment: you can this this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36841461/error-android-emulator-gets-killed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36841461/error-android-emulator-gets-killed)

Comment: I have already visited that one and I tried everything from there. It still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

newbie here but wanted to learn more about developing apps, so downloaded Android Studio to do an intro lesson and was frustrated by the same issue -emulator was "killed" before opening. Well, I think I saw a vague suggestion somewhere to uninstall Emulator using SDK Manager (SDK Manager - System Settings - Android SDK - SDK Tools), then reinstalling from same place (SDK Manager). Voila! It worked for me. The emulator works and I see my virtual device. As a newbie you can imagine how cryptic this all was for me, but it's one way to learn, I guess!

Comment: I have also tried this which doesn't work. I knoew get this error

11:26 AM Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)

Comment: This is really beyond the scope of my knowledge, but just one last thing: you probably want to be deleting the AVD and starting fresh, just want to make sure you are doing that? I was having troubles and then remembered to delete the AVD and make a new one, and that seemed to work for me.

Comment: Also did that, didn't work. I kind of figured out. I just have to run the emulator through the cmd. I do that by using the command: emulator -avd (Name of the emulator). Not the best solution but it works.