# Android Emulator not working Android Studio

Tags: android, emulation

So recently I installed Android Studio for work at college, but can't make the emulator work and I don't know how?. I installed everything it needs HAXM and etc and the process is always getting killed, tried to look at the Command-Line and no errors are found.
Any Tip?
[Command Line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTmdL.png)

[Devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7BoJ.png)

[Run Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoP7p.png)

[SDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQ0Pu.png)

Comment: Do you really need emulator. I hate it: too slow. In any case you must test your app on physicals device.

Comment: Yes really need it, dont have another way sadly

Comment: Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36841461/error-android-emulator-gets-killed

Answer (score 0):

You should first check if your system meets the requirements: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator#requirements

Then simply follow the official tutorial in the Android Dev Docs: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator#install

If then still errors appear you should take a look at the logcat in Android Studio.

Comment: I there, yes i meet the requirents, since i have a I7-10875H and a RTX 2070 Super, i can connect my phone and use it, but cant get the emulator to work...

Comment: Also i can use VirtualBox, so maybe we can exclude the VM problem i guess