# Android emulator with google play was killed in android studio 4.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I have faced this issue on windows 10:

[image: The emulator process for AVD was killed.]

I have checked other solutions such as this question:

- [ERROR Android emulator gets killed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36841461/1105277)

One of the answers to this question suggests to change **graphics to software**, but it is not possible for devices with **google play**. I created a new emulator without google play and changed graphic to software, and it worked fine, but I need a solution for google play devices, which the graphics option is mute and unchangeable.

[image]

Comment: It's a bug from an android studio. Go to setting->Tools->Emulator-> Uncheck launch in a tool window. Just use it as separate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a bug in Android Studio 4.1. It was solved by unchecking launch in tool windows:

```
Settings -> Tools -> Emulator -> Uncheck Launch in a tool window
```

I have reported this issue to google:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/171901410

Answer (score 0):

Change "Graphics" to "Software" is worked for me.

1. Go to: Tools > Android > AVD Manager
2. Press the "edit" (pencil) icon next to your AVD
3. Change "Graphics" to "Software".

In my case it was disabled.

[image]

So, I follow these steps.

1. [image]
2. [image]
3. [image]