# Emulator process for AVD was killed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I just downloaded Android Studio, so everything is freshly installed but I keep getting the error Emulator process for AVD was killed, :

- HAXM is installed, but also tried reinstalling it multiple times
- I do have enough disk space
- AVD API is installed
- emulator tools window, tried it with both checked and unchecked
- Environment variables are also set properly
- Also tried running avd.manager and avd in command line but emulator can't find the path or says it's not right, even if I set it in environment variables for ANDROID_SDK_ROOT (and I checked it multiple times with different paths)

The only difference I have in install is that I had to install the sdk in C:\Users\Development\Android\sdk. But it shouldn't be an issue and as I mentioned I have also tried setting the environment variables as well.

Comment: Check for HW virtualization is enabled. set path for ANDROID_HOME and JAVA. Once installed/set, restart the device (PC).

Comment: Yep, all of them enabled and set :/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36841461/error-android-emulator-gets-killed/47578244. Please follow this link.

Comment: Yep, I tried basically everything on there...

Comment: it worked for me. macOs Mojave + android studio 4.1.3 [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66750936/8126799)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and did the same things, i fixed it by uninstalling the intel x86 HAXM, run the emulator normally and it will ask you to install it before it runs, after that it worked.

Hope it works for you, cheers.