# The emulator process for AVD Nexus_10_API_28_large was killed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am trying to open the emulator but what is happening , i am getting this message

```
The emulator process for AVD Nexus_10_API_28_large was killed.
```

I am using ubuntu 18.04 OS, i tried
[ERROR Android emulator gets killed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36841461/error-android-emulator-gets-killed)

but nothing seems to be working , this happens for both mobile devices and tablet devices on emulator .

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling the option "Launch in a tool window" from Settings>Tools>Emulator.