# Error while waiting for device: The emulator process for AVD Galaxy_Nexus_API_30 was killed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I will appreciate your help on helping me to operate the emulator in Android studio 4.1.1
I have installed the latest Java SDK JRE version 1.8.0_271 and the latest android ver 4.1.1.
Did not write any code, and used the Hello World! Default  app. Just to operate the AVD but it keeps crashing right as it appears. And I get the “Error while waiting for device: The emulator process for AVD… was killed”
I searched the net and performed all action listed below and it still did not worked. For those who have similar problem maybe the list will assist you:

1. Reboot the computer
2. Change the AVD
3. Move to Software in the AVD->setup->advanced ->emulated performance->instead of auto chose software.
4. Make sure the Java is latest
5. Make JAVA_HOME and path in the environment variables.
6. Make ANDROID _HOME variable in windows environment variables.
7. Make sure the disk has plenty of space (I have more than 10G)
8. Verify there is enough RAM memory (I have 8GB installed)
9. Verify the computer bios has virtualization enabled.
10. Uncheck intel x86 Emulator Accelerator in the SDK tools menu and reinstall  HAXM 7.5.6
11. Remove and install the packages in Android SDK build –tools  latest ver 30.0.2
12. Uninstall android and erase and trace of Android in the computer to eliminate old versions and reinstall
13. Check in SDK Manager if there are any updates
14. Tried with or without  ANDROID_SDK_HOME variable
15. Reduce memory and storage size of the AVD (AVD ->advanced settings)
16. Tried all in Stack Overflow link: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36841461/error-android-emulator-gets-killed#:~:text=To%20fix%20it%20go%20to,restart%20Android%20Studio%20%2F%20your%20PC.&text=Now%2C%20when%20you%20try%20to,'%20error%20%2D%3E%20Click%20Ok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36841461/error-android-emulator-gets-killed#:%7E:text=To%20fix%20it%20go%20to,restart%20Android%20Studio%20%2F%20your%20PC.&text=Now%2C%20when%20you%20try%20to,%27%20error%20%2D%3E%20Click%20Ok).

Non of the above helped and I look for your idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are playing Valorant, try to temporarily disable Vanguard Anticheat https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/gdr6pj/android_studio_emulator_killed_by_riot_vanguard/

Comment: Hi Thanks no, I do not play Valorant. I simply new to Android and the error happened using it for the first time after installation.