# AVD Emulator On Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

Hello i have the latest android studio , **sdk up to date, and intel HAXM installed and checked!! in the sdk tools**
when i add a new Virtual device on AVD i click play and its show this ERROR!!
im also check on the command if the intel haxm running and its runing!

i was try a lot of solutions and i don't understand why its not working i have all the necessary things to run emulator!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Similar to : [ERROR Android emulator gets killed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36841461/error-android-emulator-gets-killed)

Probably a problem of free space on the disk or the ANDROID_HOME path in environment variable is incorrect.