# Android Studio raises this error: 'The emulator process for AVD was killed.'

Tags: android

I am trying to learn Android Development in Android Studio.
I installed the requirements:

[image]

but nothing works, it just raises an error, and the error says, 'The emulator process for AVD was killed.'

Comment: many things can cause this error. check  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36841461/error-android-emulator-gets-killed)

Comment: @MeBottleOScrumpy i have enough space, and i installed HAXM and everything and i tried to wipe data and its still not working...

Comment: this worked for me 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67288845/8899344

Answer (score 2):

With the new macOS Big Sur 11.3 update, the emulator in Android Studio no longer runs. This error occurs because Apple has made changes to the hypervisor entitlements.

### Steps to fix the issue:

1. Open Terminal and go to the directory

```
cd <ANDROID_SDK_ROOT>/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64
```

In my case 
 cd ~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64

2. Create an xml file named entitlements.xml with touch or cat commands.

```
touch entitlements.xml
```

3. Add this content to the entitlements.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.hypervisor</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

4. Then simply sign the qemu-system-x86_64 with it:

```
codesign -s - --entitlements entitlements.xml --force qemu-system-x86_64
```

Now simply restart Android Studio and the Android Emulator should work again!

Comment: Updating to Android Emulator 3.5.6 should fix this now.