# How to fix “The emulator process for AVD was killed” in MAC OSX Yosemite 10

Tags: android, emulation, android-virtual-device

I've installed android studio 4.2 and when i try to start avd manager, this errors appear bellow "The emulator process for AVD was killed”"

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cy4jR.png)[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZOEb.png)

I've tried with different virtual devices, different APIs versions and images but i get same error.

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance,

Kind regards.

SeaL

Comment: What is your Macbook processor?

Comment: 2,7 GHz Intel Core i5

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36841461/error-android-emulator-gets-killed This may help. check once

Comment: Thanks, but before post my question, i've tried all of this possible solutions. A virtual device with software properties, another image R, or Pie, q...update my Emulator, uninstall my emulator and install it again, haxm intall again....but nothing results....ai think is for my SO because i see in android page that requeriments are for version upper than Yosemite...