# What are the requirements/prerequisites and how to create ARM64 ABI in AVD Manager

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, arm64, avd-manager

I am trying to create a device in ADV manager with ABI ARM64 AVI to test my react-native app. I have created one but it won't open, AVD manager message is "The emulator process for AVD Pixel_3_API_28 was killed" I would like to know the system requirements in creating one. My machine is an Intel Core 5 desktop, and running 64 bit Windows 10. I don't have any problems creating ABI x86. Thank you.

Comment: Your processor, because it has x86 instructions, cannot interpret ARM instructions. Always use x86 and x64 emulators.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR Android emulator gets killed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36841461/error-android-emulator-gets-killed)