# Flutter kurulumunda Android toolchain - develop for Android devices hatası

Tags: flutter, sdk, android-emulator

Herkese selamlar ben kurulum yaparken cmd de  andriod toolchan kısmında kırmızı çarpı  alıyor ve uzunca bir ifade söz konusu ne yapmam gerekiyor. Yardımcı olursanız çok sevinirim :)
Hata budur;
(Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
X Unable to locate Android SDK.
Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
(or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions).
If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, please use
`flutter config --android-sdk` to update to that location.)

Answer (score 1):

Salam. Android Studionu düzgün şəkildə qurduğunuzdan əmin olun.

Sonra Android studio nu açın > SDK manager > Android SDK > Yuxarıdan SDK Tools bölümünü açın > android SDK command-line tools(latest) qurun. (şəkildəki kimi olmalıdır)

Bütün android sdk lisenziyaları qəbul edin.

1. terminalı açın
2. flutter doctor --android-licenses
3. bütün lisenziyaları qəbul etmək üçün y

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hemen deniyorum

Comment: Hocam dediğiniz aşamaları gerçekleştirdim ancak bu sefer de okuma zaman aşımına uğradı diye bir hata verdi.(An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android Emulator: Read timed out.)

Comment: Android Studionu Administrator modunda açıb sonra yenidən təkrar edin.

Comment: Dediğiniz şekilde yaptım hata vermedi ancak bu sefer de emülatör seçimi yaptım çalıştırayım derken şöyle bir cevap aldım;   The emulator process for AVD Nexus_6P_API_28 has termninated.    Yani emülatörü açamıyorum hata bu kısımda...

Comment: Bu forma baxın, səbəbləri fərqli ola bilər.  Yuxarıya yeni şəkil əlavə etdim https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36841461/error-android-emulator-gets-killed-in-android-studio