# Android Studio Emulator "The emulator process for AVD was killed"

Tags: flutter, android-studio, android-emulator

**The emulator process for AVD Pixel_4_API_300a was killed.**

I turned on virtualization, installed the missing tools. I downloaded the JDK. I read many threads and ideas to solve it but it didn't work.

```
LOG:
Emulator: C:\Users\emir\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Pixel_4_API_300a 
Emulator: INFO    | Android emulator version 31.3.10.0 (build_id 8807927) (CL:N/A) 
Emulator: emulator: INFO: path_getAvdSystemPath: AVD Pixel_4_API_300a has path C:\Users\emir\.android\avd\Pixel_4_API_300.avd 
Emulator: PANIC: Cannot find AVD system path. Please define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT 
Emulator: emulator: INFO: path_getAvdSystemPath: trying to check whether C:\Program Files\Android\Sdk is a valid sdk root 
Emulator: emulator: WARN: path_getAvdSystemPath: C:\Program Files\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-30\google_apis_playstore\x86\ is not a valid directory. 
Emulator: emulator: WARN: path_getAvdSystemPath: emulator has searched the above paths but found no valid sdk root directory.
Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here is output of `flutter doctor`:

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQsJC.png)

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/q/36841461/10157127 answer your quesiton

Comment: I tried the solutions, failed.