# The emulator avd process failed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

Can someone please help me out over here?

I recently installed the latest version of Android Studio, after installing it I tried running my android emulator to see if it was working, but this error message popped up:

> the emulator process for avd has failed

Before you say its due to insufficient memory, here's my laptop specs:

**Laptop:** Dell Latitude E5440
**OS:** Windows 10 22H2
**RAM:** 8GB
**HDD:** 1TB
**CPU Architecture:** x64

I have used an early version of Android studio on this laptop before and everything worked correctly.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36841461/error-android-emulator-gets-killed-in-android-studio)

Comment: I've already tried that but it don't work